# Completing Applet Calculator

Tags: java, swing, applet

As my first applet, I'm making a calculator (only adding at the moment), but I am stuck at figuring out how to get numbers from the listeners. So far I have:

```
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class calculator extends JApplet {

    private JTextField num1;
    private JTextField num2;
    private JButton calculate;
    private JLabel result;
    private double numOne,numTwo;
    private double sum = numOne + numTwo;

    public void init() {
        num1 = new JTextField("",9);
        num2 = new JTextField("",9);
        calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        result = new JLabel("The Answer is: " + sum);

        num1.addActionListener(new num1Listener());
        num2.addActionListener(new num2Listener());
        calculate.addActionListener(new doMath());

        add(num1);
        add(num2);
        add(calculate);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(200,200);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("The answer is " + sum, 20, 20);
    }
    class num1Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String num1input = num1.getText();
            numOne = Double.parseDouble(num1input);
            }
    }
    class num2Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String num2input = num2.getText();
            numTwo = Double.parseDouble(num2input);
        }
    }
    class doMath implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            add(result);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get my numOne and numTwo doubles from inside these listeners and into my code? I would like to add them together and store them in the sum variable.

Comment: 1) See also this [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).  It uses `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the expression in the text area. 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0):

Store them as instance fields within your code...

```
public class calculator extends JApplet {
    private double number1, number2;
```

Then assign them the values from the fields...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String num1input = num1.getText();
    number1 = Double.parseDouble(num1input);
```

Having said all that.  I might be better to have an "equals" button, which when clicked, gets the values from the text fields, converts them to `double`s sums them and displays the result on the screen in one step, rather than trying to use the text fields individually, but that's just me

**Updated**

In order to display the result, you first need to get the numbers...

```
double number1 = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText());
double number2 = Double.parseDouble(num2.getText());
```

You need to sum them together...

```
sum = number1 + number2;
```

Then you need to update the `result` label...

```
result.setText(Double.toString(sum));
```

Doing...

```
private double sum = numOne + numTwo;
```

Will only add the CURRENT values of `numOne` and `numTwo` together, which, but default, are `0`, so it has no meaning...

As a leaner, I would advise against using `JApplet` to learn with, applets have there own issues which are difficult enough for experienced developers to diagnose, stick to good old desktop windows

As an example...

```
public class Calculator extends JApplet {

    private JTextField num1;
    private JTextField num2;
    private JButton calculate;
    private JLabel result;
    private double numOne, numTwo;
    private double sum = numOne + numTwo;

    public void init() {
        num1 = new JTextField("", 9);
        num2 = new JTextField("", 9);
        calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        result = new JLabel("The Answer is: " + sum);

        calculate.addActionListener(new DoMath());

        add(num1);
        add(num2);
        add(calculate);
        add(result);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(200, 200);
    }

    class DoMath implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                double number1 = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText());
                double number2 = Double.parseDouble(num2.getText());
                result.setText(Double.toString(number1 + number2));
            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                result.setText("Bad values, fix em");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm now trying to make the button listener function. Why will it not work if I have the listener add(result) one actionEvent?

Comment: 1. Don't override `paint` for this, it's way more then you need. 2.  Try calling `invalidate();` and `repaint()` after `add(result);` to force the layout manager to update the UI

Comment: I followed your steps and it all works, except the two numbers aren't adding and storing in sum.

Comment: ...When do you actually add them together...? Shouldn't that be done within the `doMath` listener?

Comment: Yes, I added sum = numOne + numTwo into the doMath listener, and it still isn't giving me a correct answer

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I'll definitely be sticking to desktop windows after this project (had to do a JApplet for school)